# Highcharts spiderweb showing wrong categories at first position

Tags: highcharts

On the y-axis of the spider chart, it reads 0, 100, 20, 30, ... 
While the interval is 10 and max value is 100.

How can I make sure Highcharts shows the correct order: 0, 10, 20, ..., 100.

This is a fiddle to show the issue I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/8g9q3ubd/

```
"yAxis": {
    "gridLineInterpolation": "polygon",
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "pointInterval": 10,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "tickAmount": 10,
    "tickInterval": 10,
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
    "categories": ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100"]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `categories` property. With `tickInterval: 10` only every tenth category is shown and your last category ("100") is shown in second place.

```
"yAxis": {
    "gridLineInterpolation": "polygon",
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "pointInterval": 10,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "tickAmount": 11,
    "tickInterval": 10,
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on"
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fmo31h7n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.categories